# Unable to to render a bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am trying to render a bootstrap modal popup window based login for that I have included 
 in my _header.html.erb file as below

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3 id="myModalLabel">Log in</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
        <%= link_to "View", signin_path %>

         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
         </div>
         </div>
```

But I was not displaying any  signin button on the screen But when I try to see source code of my web page there I have having the link as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title> Skillable App </title> 
   <!-- Javascripts
    ================================================== -->
   <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
   <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
    <!-- Stylesheets
    ================================================== -->
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/companyrating.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/global.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/user_session.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="/UOprUnr0t8ItxVtX1Yc1GaaX3zgs2/kCFicNAtWM68=" name="csrf-token" />
   <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

 <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container">
      <a href="/" id="logo">SAMPLE</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="/">Companies_list</a></li>

            <li><div class="modal hide fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

         <a href="/signin">View</a>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
         </div>
         </div></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I have also used <%= render "/sessions/new.html.erb"%> but I am getting the following error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#companies_list

Showing /home/seshendra/rails_app-master/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #22 raised:

Missing partial sessions/new.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/seshendra/rails_app-master/app/views"
<%= render "/sessions/new.html.erb"%>
```

So  can any one please tell me how to solve it. I am totally a newbie I have gone through this website http://raycoding.net/2012/10/30/creating-social-network-on-ruby-on-rails-day-5-navigationstwitter-bootstrap-stylesjquery-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

try removing first slash ('/') on path
use

```
 <%= render "sessions/new.html.erb" %>
```